# Facebook: Unable to set privacy for album

Tags: privacy, facebook

Even if I click Edit album, the drop-down to choose privacy is not shown. It's not clear what needs to be done to make the album private.

Answer (score -1):

If the album is "showcased in the profile" then it automatically is Public. To not "showcase" the album anymore, open it and next to the name of the album you have the Edit button and next to it is the button that will remove the album from the profile.

[image]